# Where did the Twitter Profile RSS Feed go?

Tags: twitter, rss, feeds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you find a Twitter RSS feed?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/how-do-you-find-a-twitter-rss-feed)

I can't find my Twitter Profile RSS feed (icon) on the "new Twitter".

Can anyone find it, or tell me how to get the feed URL for my own profile stream?

Answer (score 1):

- [Friend's timeline](http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.rss)
- Replies: twitter.com/statuses/replies.rss

I found these by just hitting "View Source" and searching for "RSS" ;-)

RSS feeds always have a `link` tag with the attributes `rel="alternate"` and `type="application/rss+xml"`

Comment: but that link requires a "login and password for the twitter api", where is the regular RSS feed link that was on the other page?

Comment: You're right about the login. I cannot find the old RSS feed button on the new twitter either - their help page is not yet updated: http://support.twitter.com/entries/15361-how-to-find-your-rss-feed What you can do though is to simply leave the preview (you can join it later again) to get the button again. The public RSS feeds are simply in the form http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/<useridhere>.rss

Comment: the RSS feed link you provide is retrieves a list of tweets from a year ago. :(

Answer (score 1):

Now it's this:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/(User Account ID).rss
```

For example, for [Clay Shirky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_Shirky) (http://twitter.com/cshirky) the RSS URL is:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/cshirky.rss
```

Comment: This no longer works. There is [a new way to fetch a feed](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36772/17121).

Answer (score 0):

As Twitter stopped supporting RSS feeds I'm afraid you can't use it anymore.

You can still get your RSS feed by switching to old Twitter view. You will find an RSS link to half bottom right side and look something like this:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline/XXX.rss
```

The `XXX` is your user ID number. Replace `XXX` with your user ID if you can't switch to the old Twitter.

To find your user ID go to something like [ID From User](http://www.idfromuser.com/) and type in your Twitter username.