# How do you find a Twitter RSS feed?

Tags: twitter, rss, feeds

Given a Twitter username, where do you find the RSS feed for that user?

Comment: For post API v1.1 changes, I've answered on a separate [question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/any-alternatives-for-twitter-rss-after-native-service-is-shut-down): http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45963/42726

Answer (score 11):

Give this a try:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/{username}.rss
```

Replace `{username}` with the Twitter user ID.
Now, how to get the ID? Just switch to the old Twitter and go to your profile. There it is, the RSS feed link! Just hover over it, and you would know the Twitter user ID.

Comment: you can also replace .rss with .json to change the format.

Comment: It is working! The RSS feed for http://twitter.com/aurora_alerts is http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/aurora_alerts.rss

Comment: Is there a way to get the ID without having to join Twitter?

Comment: See the answer below - you don't need the numeric ID, the username will work.

Comment: This no longer works. There is [a new way to fetch a feed](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36772/17121).

Answer (score 9):

This bookmarklet will show you where the feed is for any user.

http://alexch.github.com/bookmarklets/

Twitter isn't telling you the whole story. The feeds are there and they update. They just took the link out of the user interface. The bookmarklet puts them back. :-)

Answer (score 7):

As explained in https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#11716 `http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.rss` is no longer supported.

The correct way to get a Twitter feed is now as follows:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=username
```

Obviously you will have to replace `username` with the user name who's feed you are after.

Comment: Unfortunately this is also going to be deprecated (this month, in fact). See https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11582 for details. I'm not sure there will be any alternatives, but I'll ask a question about that.

Comment: Yep, no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

You can even get your profile's RSS feed!

The pattern is

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.rss
```

where `username` the Twitter username (for example, `cshirky`).

I tried it, and it works! You just don't need to know the numeric user ID.

Comment: This no longer works. There is [a new way to fetch a feed](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36772/17121).

Answer (score 2):

I made a tool, *[Twitter RSS Feed Getter](http://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/twitter_rss)*, to retrieve RSS feeds for Twitter users. You just type a username into the input field and press the *Fetch RSS* button.

Answer (score 0):

Use search.twitter.com (Advanced) then gram the "Feed for this query" link from the top left: **http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=+from%3A{USER}**

i.e. http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=+from%3Aaplusk for Ashton Kutcher (aplusk).

Comment: Twitter's public search API isn't very reliable. It won't give you posts older than a certain limit (which they vary based on traffic), and it's also subject to throttling. Use the main site's RSS link instead -- at least until they disable it instead of just hiding it -- which you can find with a click using http://alexchaffee.com/bookmarklets/#twitterrss

Comment: This is not supported anymore "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview."